# Dynamic memory allocation php

Tags: php, memory

I'm using the ImageMagick library for an image compression script that I'm writing. Since it's supposed to process a lot of images in separate folders, I'm having some trouble with memory allocation.

Is there a way to allocate more memory if the default memory limit isn't sufficient to process the images?

Note: *I don't want to set a limit before the script runs.*

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/97340/imagemagicks-convert-utility-takes-too-much-memory-with-pdf-input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a raw solution that seems to work well. After a research on the php manual, I wrote this code to achieve the dynamic memory allocation task.
Here is the code:

*NB: The memInfo function snippet is taken from a comment on the php manual page about the `memory_get_usage()` page*

```php
<?php 

if( memInfo(memory_get_usage(true)) > '128MB' ){
    ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
}

function memInfo( int $size ){
    $unit = ['B','KB','MB','GB','TB','PB'];
    return @round( $size / pow(1024, ($i = floor(log($size,1024)))),2).$unit[$i];
}
```